# Android jetpack compose androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.items

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Newbie here, just wanted to know the difference between these two snippets

I was working with lazyVerticalGrid for the first time and wrote this code which worked as intended

```
    LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(2)) {
        items(DataSource.topics.size) {
            CourseCard(topic = DataSource.topics[it])
        }
    }
```

But, found out there is another way which apparently involves adding an import statement too,

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.items

    LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(2)) {
        items(DataSource.topics) {
            CourseCard(topic = it)
        }
    }
```

What's the difference, what is the right way?

I tried ctrl+click on the items() function before import and after import, it takes me to the same LazyGridDsl.kt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is generic one, you just pass number of items and then it gives you index and you have to get the correct item yourself every time - not just inside `itemContent`, there's also `key`, `span` and `contentType`. It's a member function of `LazyGridScope`, therefore you don't need an import to use it.

The second one is just a nicer alternative to the first one when you have a list of items - it basically just calls the first one and calls the `items[index]` for you, so you can just work with the item straight away. Unlike the first one, it's an extension function of `LazyGridScope`, therefore you need an import to use it.

There is no right way, either is fine. If you have a list of items, you can use the second one and save yourself the `items[index]` call. But sometimes, you might need the index as well (for example to treat first/last item differently), then you can use the first one.